# telethon sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Tags: python, sqlite, bots, telegram-bot, telethon

So basically i am creating telegram python bot. It's running fine in my local system. I created two diffrerent scripts, one for taking message from one channel and second one is for processing that message and using bot i am sending that message to another channel. Till now all the things were running smoothly. Issue occured after i deployed it in fly.io with same session name. I tried lots of things and tricks. But not able to solve the issue.

Here is my complete code :

telethon_client.py

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
from celery import Celery
import os
import json


# Initialize the Celery app
app = Celery('tasks', broker=broker_url)

# Initialize the Telethon client
client = TelegramClient(session_file, api_id, api_hash)

# Set up an event handler to listen for new messages
# @client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def telethon_new_message(event):
    chat_title = event.chat.title
    message_text = event.message.text

    if chat_title in chat_titles:
        # Send a task to the Celery worker
        app.send_task("tasks.handle_new_message", args=[message_text])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Start the Telethon client
    with TelegramClient(session_file, api_id, api_hash) as client:
        client.start()
        client.connect()
        client.add_event_handler(telethon_new_message, events.NewMessage())
        print("Listening for new messages...")
        client.disconnect()
```

Here is my celery worker

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
from celery import Celery
from helper import count_non_flipkart_links_and_messages, get_amazon_product_category, find_tag, keep_tag_param, send_telegram_message, expand_short_url
import os
import asyncio

# Initialize the Celery app
app = Celery('tasks', broker=broker_url)

# Function to handle incoming messages
@app.task
def handle_new_message(message_text):
    print(f"New message: {message_text}")
    link_count, corresponding_messages = count_non_flipkart_links_and_messages(message_text)

    updated_message = str(message_text)

    for message in corresponding_messages:
        current_url = expand_short_url(message)
        # category, current_url = get_amazon_product_category(message)

        if current_url != "":
            updated_url = find_tag(current_url)
            updated_message = updated_message.replace(message, keep_tag_param(updated_url))


    print(updated_message)

    asyncio.run(send_telegram_message(sending_channel, updated_message))

    print("Message sent successfully!")
```

After deploying it runs smooth for sometime but after some time they are saying due to using same session file name in different ips. Sqlite DB Got Locked. Can anyone please help with this ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kashyap/projects/telegram-bot/telethon_client.py", line 37, in <module>
    with TelegramClient(session_file, api_id, api_hash) as client:
  File "/home/kashyap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 308, in __init__
    session.set_dc(
  File "/home/kashyap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telethon/sessions/sqlite.py", line 168, in set_dc
    self._update_session_table()
  File "/home/kashyap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telethon/sessions/sqlite.py", line 194, in _update_session_table
    c.execute('delete from sessions')
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Comment: https://arabic-telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-references/faq.html#sqlite3-operationalerror-database-is-locked

Answer (score 0):

Celery likely uses threads. Telethon uses `asyncio`.

You can combine `asyncio` and `threading`, but it's not trivial.

If you don't need Celery or the features `threading` provides, you can use `asyncio` directly to spawn as many tasks as you need.

Otherwise, you should probably have a single dedicated thread with a single `asyncio` event loop and Telethon running in it. Then communicate with it via e.g. queues.

Or you can search for Celery with `asyncio` to learn what can be done.